# WPF disable click on ComboBoxItem

Tags: wpf, combobox, click

I have a ComboBoxItem that acts strictly as a section title.  Visually, I have it set but how do I eat the click when something is selected?

I would prefer to accomplish this in xaml, if possible. TIA

Comment: Anyone who wants to enter ComboBoxItem as a tag, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by using the 'IsEnabled' property on the ComboBoxItem.  In my quick test, this:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False">Item2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Results in a ComboBox with 3 items, and "Item2" does not get selected when clicked.

Comment: That would give it the default disabled try (which I could work around) but it doesn't work if I've MouseOvered a live item.  So, if I click the first item that is a title, no problem.  If I MouseOver a live item -- thus selecting it -- and click on the title item it accepts the click on the live MouseOvered item.  Could be my Styles and templates but I thought there might be a property...  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting.  Perhaps there is something happening with the style, relating to the Select-on-MouseOver functionality (it doesn't do this with the default style).  A possible solution for that problem would be to handle the PreviewMouseDown event on the title item and cancel the click.  This might require some work in code behind, though.